# python-devel and dependent rpm packages download for SUSE 12 SP4

Tags: python, suse, sles, zypper

I want to install python-devel and it's dependent packages on SUSE 12 SP4. Can you please direct me to the official SUSE package manager site? Using Yast I couldn't find the python-devel package. I did "zypper search python-devel" but couldn't find anything. Please guide me how to install python-devel on SUSE 12 SP4.

Answer (score 2):

You might be searching for the wrong package name. SLE packages can be searched at https://packagehub.suse.com/search/ and for openSUSE https://software.opensuse.org.
If you just search for "python" you'll see all related packages.

Answer (score 1):

I am on SLES 12 SP5, so this may be different now, but I do see devel packages for both python 2 and python 3 with the commands below. Use `zypper search -h` to learn more.

### `zypper search -s python-devel python3-devel`

```
% zypper search -s python-devel python3-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                 | Type    | Version        | Arch   | Repository
--+----------------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------------------
  | dbus-1-python-devel  | package | 1.2.0-4.194    | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_SDK
  | dbus-1-python3-devel | package | 1.2.0-4.194    | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_SDK
  | python-devel         | package | 2.7.17-28.51.1 | x86_64 | SLES12_STD_2020_11
  | python-devel         | package | 2.7.13-28.36.1 | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_updates
  | python-devel         | package | 2.7.13-28.31.1 | x86_64 | SLES12SP5
  | python-devel         | package | 2.7.13-28.31.1 | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_Pool
  | python3-devel        | package | 3.4.10-25.52.1 | x86_64 | SLES12_STD_2020_11
  | python3-devel        | package | 3.4.10-25.45.1 | x86_64 | SLES12_STD_2020_05
  | python3-devel        | package | 3.4.6-25.34.2  | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_SDK_updates
  | python3-devel        | package | 3.4.6-25.29.1  | x86_64 | SLES12SP5_SDK
```

### `zypper search 'python*devel'`

```
%zypper search 'python*devel'
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                   | Summary                                                           | Type
--+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
  | python-cairo-devel     | Headers for python-cairo                                          | package
  | python-devel           | Include Files and Libraries Mandatory for Building Python Modules | package
  | python-gobject2-devel  | Python bindings for GObject                                       | package
  | python-gtk-devel       | Files needed to build wrappers for GTK+ addon libraries           | package
  | python-ldb-devel       | Development files for the Python bindings for the LDB library     | package
  | python-notify-devel    | Python bindings for libnotify                                     | package
  | python-numpy-devel     | Development files for numpy applications                          | package
  | python-pyzmq-devel     | Development files for python-pyzmq                                | package
  | python-qt4-devel       | PyQt - devel part of python bindings for Qt 4                     | package
  | python-sip-devel       | SIP tool to create python bindings                                | package
  | python-talloc-devel    | Developer tools for the Talloc library                            | package
  | python-xcb-proto-devel | Python libraries mandatory for XML-XCB Development                | package
  | python3-cairo-devel    | Development files for python3-cairo                               | package
  | python3-devel          | Include Files and Libraries Mandatory for Building Python Modules | package
  | python3-gobject-devel  | Python bindings for GObject                                       | package
```